# A kind of brute-force attack

Tags: list, sum, brute-force

To achieve a project in my studies, i have to solve a problem on python and i need some help.

Indeed, i want to browse all the possibilities of a problem and i have ideas but that's not such clear for me.

Here is the problem :

- 233  200 134 167
- 234  187 172 196
- 237  220 133 163
- 241  159 193 165

We have to find how we must place each truck for each inboud/outbound.
A column represent the loading of a truck and the numbers, the number of products.

For example, if we place the truck A in the first inbound (233), the truck B in the second inbound (187), the truck C in the third inbound (133) and the truck D in the fourth inbound (165) we have a sum of 233+187+133+165=**718**

Our goal is to minimize this sum. For example, if we change just the truck A and the truck B, we have a sum of 234+200+133+165=732 this is not better than before.

So, ***how we could obtain the sum of the all possibilities of the placement of the trucks ?*** There is 24 possibilites, we have wrote them in excel, and the best possibilities is the placement  for the truck A (234), the placement 4 for the truck B (159), the placement 1 for the truck C (134) and the placement 3 for the truck D (163) which have a sum of **690** !

I will use the lists, and i know how we could obtain a number in a list, how to create a list etc.. make a sum with number of a list, but how we could obtain all the calculation we could make by excel for example like the twice i wrote before.

Sincerely yours,

Comment: ``itertools.permutations(range(4))`` will generate the 24 possible permutations of the numbers 0..3 (you could use ``range(1,5)`` for numbers 1..4 as in your text, but that's far less convenient for indexing into lists).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for "permutations".

However, with this :

```
for elt in itertools.product([233,234,237,241],[200,187,220,159],[134,172,133,193],[167,196,163,165]):
print(elt)
```

I have this answer (a part of the answer, don't the all answer, so many possibilities)

```
   (233, 200, 134, 167)(233, 200, 134, 196)(233, 200, 134, 163)(233, 200, 134, 165)(233, 200, 172, 167)(233, 200, 172, 196)(233, 200, 172, 163)
(233, 200, 172, 165)(233, 200, 133, 167)(233, 200, 133, 196)(233, 200, 133, 163(233, 200, 133, 165)(233, 200, 193, 167)(233, 200, 193, 196)(233, 200, 193, 163)(233, 200, 193, 165)(233, 187, 134, 167)(233, 187, 134, 196)(233, 187, 134, 163)(233, 187, 134, 165)(233, 187, 172, 167)(233, 187, 172, 196)(233, 187, 172, 163)(233, 187, 172, 165)(233, 187, 133, 167)(233, 187, 133, 196)
```

In fact, we can't put the 233 with the 200 in the same list because its the same truck and the same truck can not be at two inbound different. So my question is : **How can i change the function product (i think the problem came by this function) to have for example (233,187,133,165)(233,187,193,163) ?**

Here is the function product :

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
# product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
# product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
result = [[]]
for pool in pools:
    result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
for prod in result:
    yield tuple(prod)
```